# How to make my Gtk Window Transparent

Tags: c, window, background-image, glade, gtk2

Below this is the image(also used in another question here) of a my Glade Window, where you can see the **blue background** seen only in a small part instead of the whole window. Why this is so? What shouls I do?

[image]

The widgets stack is as follows:

> - GtkWindow
> - **GtkVerBox:**
>
>   1.GtkHorButtonBox(where there is 1 simple-Button and 4 Radio-buttons)
>
>   2.**GtkHorBox:**
>
>   a.GtkScrollWin->GtkViewport->GtkFrameBox->GtkVerButtonBox->GtkButtons
>
>   b.**GtkViewport->GtkVerBox:**
>
>   - GtkViewport->GtkHorButtonBox(2 Radio-buttons)
>   - GtkViewport->GtkHorBox->GtkLabels

My codes for this are as follows!

```
void Second_Window()
{  
  GtkBuilder*builder;
  GError    *error = NULL;

/*Initialize Gtk*/
  gtk_init( NULL, NULL );

/*Inialize a builder to call the glade window created*/
  builder = gtk_builder_new();
     if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "/home/ub/Desktop/myGUI.glade", &error ) )
     {
         g_warning( "%s", error->message );
         g_free( error );
     }
/*Create and find the window*/
  secondWindow = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "secondWindow" ) );
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (secondWindow), "IPC_Settings!!!" );

/*The Background Image*/
  secondImage = load_pixbuf_from_file ("dlm.jpg");
  gdk_pixbuf_render_pixmap_and_mask (secondImage, &background2, NULL, 0);
  style2 = gtk_style_new ();
  style2->bg_pixmap [0] = background2;
  gtk_widget_set_style (GTK_WIDGET(secondWindow), GTK_STYLE (style2));

/*For Buttons In Second Window*/ 
  sW_VBbox = gtk_vbutton_box_new();
  sW_VBbox = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "v_button_box2") );
}
```

I am kind of going mad to solve this. Immediate help and suggestions are very much welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using Python or C? Also I think that without the code it's kinda hard to help you

Comment: @rsm its for c :) after a long wait. can you help me in c?

Comment: I only do python, but I think that if you want help you will need to post your code. We can not guess what you are doing wrong!

Comment: @rsm Take a look at my codes. Wish to get some help now!